using gprof -pg flag doesn't generate gmon.out
I have a code that is a mix of Fortran, C and R. it's a simulation code. The backend/solver is in Fortran and C and R is used as the wrapper for creating simulation workflow and launching the process.
I would like to do some profiling using gprof so what I did is I added the relevant flags to my makefiles. Here is the structure of directories:
Let's say my code is located in the following path
/home/myusername/DEV/simcode/src

The parent makefile is located in src then I have the following sub-makefiles
src/Global/fortran/Makefile
src/TS/c/Makefile
src/TS/fortran/ReadModelData/Makefile
src/TS/fortran/RunSim/Makefile

So I modified all my sub-makefiles in the following fashion:
FC=gfortran
LD=gfortran
OPT=-O2
DBG=-g
PROF= -pg
ifdef SYSTEMROOT
# Windows OS
    SIM_GLOBAL = libCodeGlobal.dll
    FFLAGS = $(OPT) $(DBG) -cpp -fno-underscoring $(PROF)
    LDFLAGS = $(OPT) $(DBG) $(PROF)
else
    ifeq ($(shell uname),Linux)
# GNU/Linux OS
        SIM_GLOBAL = libCodeGlobal.so
        FFLAGS = $(OPT) $(DBG) -cpp -fPIC -fno-underscoring $(PROF)
        LDFLAGS = $(OPT) $(DBG) $(PROF)
    else
# Mac OSX
        SIM_GLOBAL = libCodeGlobal.dylib
        FFLAGS = $(OPT) $(DBG) -cpp -fno-underscoring $(PROF)
        LDFLAGS = $(OPT) $(DBG) $(PROF)
    endif
endif

I modified all Makefiles in the same manner as they are pretty much the same. The I ran
make clean
make all

In
/home/myusername/DEV/simcode/src

Where my parent Makefile is located. Then I ran
R CMD INSTALL .

This is how I install my code, this installs my code on a path such as
/home/myusername/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/MYCODE

where my *so files are located.
Then simply opened an R session by typing R in terminal and loading my code in it
library(MYCODE)

Then running a simulation test case
source("path to the test case file which is an `R` script")

Based on what I understood this process should create a file called gmon.out which is the could be used to analyze the performance using gprof, but I don't get the gmon.out file.
I checked the installation of gprof and it is installed, i also ran a simple test case to see if it creates gprof file and it properly did, so the problem should be coming from my Simulation code and probably my makefiles.
Any help would be appreciated. Concerning my operating system I'm working on linux if it helps.

My understanding is that the creation of the gmon.out file is triggered by the termination of the main program. Therefore, you have to link your executable with -pg so that the profiling can be initiated and terminated. I guess that here, you'd need to re-link R yourself with -pg, and even so, I'm not sure it would work. Maybe you could consider another profiler? perf maybe?

@Gilles , The linking is done during the compilation using make all and the -pg flag is taken into account during that process, so I'm not convinced that there is an extra linking process to be done with R as it is just a wrapper and and nothing more. Regarding other profilers I actually have perf and Intel VTune Profiler in mind but I kicked off with gprof and aiming to understand how it works, since it is a very common profiler.

I'm not sure of the exact way things are triggered for intiating and finalizing the profiling, but I guess that it needs to be done before the call to main(). Therefore, you have to do the linking of you main process (R here) with the -pg option.
Here is an example:
print.c:
#include <stdio.h>

int print() {
    printf( "Hello world!\n" );
    return 0;
}

print.h:
int print();

main.c:
#include "print.h"

int main() {
    return print();
}

$ gcc -pg -shared -o libprint.so print.c
$ gcc -o nopgmain main.c -L. -lprint
$ gcc -pg -o pgmain main.c -L. -lprint
$ ls
libprint.so  main.c  nopgmain  pgmain  print.c  print.h
$ ldd nopgmain pgmain 
nopgmain:
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff94bf8000)
    libprint.so => ./libprint.so (0x0000776f52628000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000776f52400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000776f52634000)
pgmain:
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdc9dde000)
    libprint.so => ./libprint.so (0x00007b6816166000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007b6815e00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007b6816172000)
$ ./nopgmain 
Hello world!
$ ls gmon.out
ls: cannot access 'gmon.out': No such file or directory
$ ./pgmain 
Hello world!
$ ls gmon.out
gmon.out

So I guess you have at least to re-link R with -pg, but I'm not sure that will suffice.
